# Quran through rootwords

Tags: quran

There is a muslim Arabic linguistic who tries to explain the quran using the root words. He has mastered clasical Arabic but hasn't Mastered aqeedah.  But he has knowledgble people arund him to correct him and teach him what he doesn't know. He basically takes a verse and tells us the context of the verse, and then dig into the root words of each word to make us understand how the word was commonly understood back then .
Is this teaching methodology correct? I.e, digging into the root words..

so that I can continue trying to understand quran from him ?

Comment: Can you give his website.

Comment: Without further information and example this is hard to answer. But this looks like a quraniste approach and in that case it would be a mix of both good and misleading approach. Because to understand the qur'an Arabic language is only one part/source of knowledge.